# React setstate not merging the old state into the new state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, react-hooks, lexical-closures

according to many examples, this should work:

```
const [_timeseries, $timeseries] = useState({hi:'lol'})

useEffect(() => {

socket.on('plot', e => {
 let keyname = Object.keys(e)[0]
 $timeseries({..._timeseries, [keyname] : value)})
}

}, [])

console.log(_timeseries) // here results in the initial state, not the set state
```

The first time it merges, it works.
But once a new event with another keyname enters, it replaces the whole thing again.
Instead of adding a new key with [keyname], the old [keyname] is being replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

The callback assigned to the `useEffect` closes the initial value of `_timeseries` in it's the lexical scope and it never updated.

To fix it, you need to use [the functional `useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) which uses the most updated state within its callback:

```
const [_timeseries, $timeseries] = useState({hi:'lol'})

useEffect(() => {
socket.on('plot', e => {
 let keyname = Object.keys(e)[0]
 $timeseries(timeSeries => {...timeseries, [keyname] : value)})
}

}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

The useState hook gives you a function which replaces the state entirely with a new value (doesn't merge it): https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

```
However, unlike this.setState in a class, updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it.
```

You can use setState with a function and merge it yourself:

```
$timeseries((old) => ({...old, [keyname] : value)}))
```

If you use it without a function it might have the old values (because you don't specify it as a dependency of useEffect)

Comment: yes, thats what i'm doing. the merge works, its just that after the second time it stops working.

Comment: @BTj84VvNNL2gh9GC you are not using a function inside $timeseries, you are using the variable _timeseries

Comment: You should use a function otherwise you might endup with wrong values

Comment: so that would work without a function if it wouldn't be for the useEffect dependecy missing?

Comment: yes, but in your case I would use a function, otherwise you would have to unsubscribe and resubscribe to the socket.

Comment: thanks it worked with the function.. it's an unintuitive behavior for me.. how is it interacting with the useffect dependency?

Comment: I recommend you read a bit about hooks here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html and https://dev.to/dan_abramov/making-sense-of-react-hooks-2eib . The main idea is that if you don't specify external values inside the dependencies array and those values update then you end up using old values in useEffect. Using a function inside setState will avoid this because it always passes the right value to that function.

Comment: If you think this answered helped you (or any answer on any question you will ask) you can mark it as approved from the leftside.

Comment: @BTj84VvNNL2gh9GC: *"how is it interacting with the useffect dependency?"* It's not. It's a feature of (the setter returned by) `useState`. If you pass a function the setter it will always pass the current value to it.